# Images in Firebase Storage, how to get them to Google Drive Team Drive

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I've built an app using Ionic that takes pictures and uploads them to Firebase Storage. What I'd like to do next is to make it so that the directory structure and images are accessible from a Google Team Drive.

What would be a good way to go about this? I don't have any code examples because I'm inexperienced with this and I don't really know where to start.

Would I write code to put in Firebase functions that would upload the images every X hours to a Google Accounts' Team Drive? Since Firebase Storage is just using Google Cloud anyways is there an API I could use? Does Firebase have this capacity already and I just don't know about it?

The Team Drive is under G Suite for my company so I could get a Google account made just for this purpose.

I'm new to Stack Overflow, sorry if this post breaks any rules.

Comment: do you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync

This is the only example on the internet that I could find that addressed this issue.

It is a working (With a few tweaks as of Novemeber 2017) example of OAuth and Google's API for uploading information from the Database to a Google Sheets document via an onWrite() event trigger.

I managed to get this working, and in combination with the Google API docs and a lot of rummaging have sort of managed to get Google Drive connected.

The key points are:
-Follow the Firebase Functions examples
-Examine the google-sheets-sync example
-Firebase Functions takes node.js javascript

Posting this answer because it sounds simple but this was a hell of a lot of digging for me to find this all.